# Fastest point-plane distance in $R^3$

Tags: geometry, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

Many questions regard computing the point-plane distance, my question in borderline with computer science, though.

> What is the *fastest* way of computing in $R^3$ the point-plane
>   distance, with the plane identified by three points?

I will try to define "fast" in two possible ways:

- as in *counting each floating point operation*
- as in *counting each SSE operation* (or similar vectorial facility),

with each operation taking the same amount of time (which is **not** realistic, but allowed in some computational models).

Thanks!

Comment: Use a single operation called **getPointPlaneDist**. Seriously, what do you mean by "operation"?

Comment: As a benchmark, if the points in the plane are $A, B, C$ and the fourth point is $P$, then the standard formula
$$
d = \frac{\left(\vec{AB}\times \vec {AC}\right)\cdot \vec{AP}}{\left\|\vec{AB}\times \vec {AC}\right\|}
$$
contains, in its most naive, direct form, $12$ multiplications, $3$ subtractions, $6$ additions, one square root and one division.

Comment: Also: will you be computing the distance to each plane for multiple points? If so, it may be worth precomputing some data (like the plane normal) and amortizing that precomputation cost. If this is a one-shot thing, though, your options are pretty limited: Arthur's answer may well be best.

Comment: @user21820 Operation is intended as the minimal operation thinkable with a floating point, i.e., sums, multiplications, ..., not intended as for instance cross product between vectors.

Comment: Well today's FPUs can do much more than just multiplications. If you want a proper answer you ought to be precise about what you allow; edit your question to include a **complete** list of the operations permitted.

Comment: The usual argument -- addition, mults, divs, subtracts should all be counted as one "op" -- mostly makes sense in the context of big-O bounds, where a constant factor is irrelevant. So it's hard to see the practical value of your question. Or is this a question which, properly framed, actually has a theoretical interest to you? If so, can you explain it?

Comment: @JohnHughes: Don't under-estimate constant factors. Often a naive implementation of computational algorithms can take 10 times as long as an efficient implementation of essentially the same algorithm. The only problem is that the asker didn't specify properly what operations are unit cost.

Comment: I was doing the opposite: I was saying that op-counting, ignoring constant factors, doesn't have much use in estimating costs of real implementations, but does have its place -- namely in big-O or big-Omega bounds on algorithmic efficiency. I must have written unclearly. I was trying to determine whether OP wanted an answer because of a practical problem ("I'm making a video game, and I need ...") where uninformed op-counting in which all ops are treated equally would be useless, or something else, where such counting might have value.

Comment: I edited the question adding FPU/SSE references. There is no applicative purpose (now), some computational model allow equal cost for operations but charge for memory transfers, so I'd like to see how "fast" I could have this simple operation in this model.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is still ill-posed, and also off-topic. Arthur's formula is fine in practice (though in practice one would try mightily to avoid computing true distance, rather than squared distance) and I doubt there is a significantly better solution (at least in the extremely unrealistic setting where square roots and FDIV count the same as additions, and cache effects can be completely neglected).

Comment: In practical implementations (using SSE/AVX/AVX2 at least) cache effects and data ordering are actually a major point. The optimum data order (whether you have the coordinates for each point consecutive, or in separate arrays), depends in particular on whether you have multiple points per plane or not. A single operation is not useful to optimize -- and Arthur's formula is the basis for all implementations I'd use --, so the real question is, whether you have many points or many planes, or both. And then we go from math to programming language and architecture specific details, really.

Comment: The interesting part (to me) is of course having one plane and many points, and achieve maximum speed with clever ordering. As you say, caching is important, and this is the reason in this question I'd like to avoid having to deal with different clock cycles for each SSE instruction.